# Is there a way to use a variable and transclude it with changing variable in case?

Tags: bash

```
function install(){

V1=version1
V2=version2
DIR=folder

echo "Select version by number to download ${reset}:"
echo "$V1"
echo "$V2"
read version

case $version in

  1) if [[ ! -d $DIR/$V1 ]]; 
        then echo "Creating $DIR/$V1 folder."
            mkdir -p $DIR
        else
            echo "$DIR/$V1 Folder exists"
     fi

  2) if [[ ! -d $DIR/$V2 ]]; 
        then echo "Creating $DIR/$V2 folder."
            mkdir -p $DIR/$V2
        else
            echo "$DIR/$V2 Folder exists"
      fi
}

opt=$1
case $opt in
    --install | -i) install ;;
    *) echo "Exit"
       exit ;;
esac
```

Now the only thing that changes in `case $version` is the variable `$V[1-2]`

How could i read a template and put in there?

I tried:

```
lines=('if [[ ! -d $DIR/$V0 ]]; 
        then echo "Creating $DIR/$V0 folder."
            mkdir -p $DIR
        else
            echo "$DIR/$V0 Folder exists"
     fi')
```

and then

```
1) $(lines | sed -e "s/\&V0/\$V1/g")
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: I am sorry, but after reading the answers i regret i was not clear enough. The main part i am asking for was:

1. I have a text with "if then else" conditions
2. That one should be somewhere as a template.
3. Then this template should be read and the variables should be exchanged by the correct ones.
4. That way i have only one script and can be reused by just putting it into "case" with little modification through sed for example.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: What does "transclude" mean?

Comment: I am sorry, i really tried to make it tiny as possible.

Comment: @Barmar https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transclusion

Comment: @Bramar and Shawn Thank you! But i better create a new post which is more specific. What is the best behavior here? Should i delete this one or should it stay?

Comment: Executing shell code stored as text is difficult to do right except in simple cases (and this isn't a simple case). I'd look at other ways to do it, such as using a function for the near-common code, and using a single array instead of a bunch of similarly-named variables. So you'd have a function like `createdir() { if [[ ! -d "$DIR/$V[$1]" ]]; ...` and call it with `createdir "$version"`

Comment: @Megavolt did you already create a new post?

Comment: @kvantour no not yet

Comment: @GordonDavisson that is neat and simple. Thanks for sharing :-) I am not really new to bash, but trying to be better.

Comment: @kvantour I created a new question with more specific information: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279474/reuse-a-function-with-modification-in-case]

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-select) builtin to generate a prompt and menu of available of options:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a versions=(version1 version2)
dir=folder

PS3="Select version by number to download: "
select version in "${versions[@]}"; do
    if [[ -z $version ]]; then
        echo "Invalid version!"
    elif [[ ! -d $dir/$version ]]; then
        echo "Creating $dir/$version folder"
        mkdir "$dir/$version"
        break
    else
        echo "$dir/$version already exists."
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign either `$V1` or `$V2` to another variable, and use that in the common code

```
case $version in
    1) v=$V1 ;;
    2) v=$V2 ;;
    *) echo "Invalid version"; exit ;;
esac

if [[ ! -d "$DIR/$v" ]]; 
then 
    echo "Creating $DIR/$v folder."
    mkdir -p "$DIR/$v"
else
    echo "$DIR/$v Folder exists"
fi
```