# Reuse a function with modification in case

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR1=folderone
DIR2=foldertwo

function template() {
    if [[ ! -d $DIR ]]; 
        then
            echo "Creating $DIR folder."
            mkdir -p $DIR
        else
            echo "$DIR Folder exists"
    fi
}

echo "Select folder by number:"
echo "1) $DIR1"
echo "2) $DIR2"
read dirnumber

case $dirnumber in
    1) template | sed -e "s/\$DIR/$DIR1/g" ;;
    2) template | sed -e "s/\$DIR/$DIR2/g" ;;
    *) echo "Good bye!"
esac


case $1 in
    -c) createdir
    ;;  
    *) exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

I have template function and use it in case. I want reuse it and exchange it with $DIR1 or $DIR2 and run the code.

DIR1 and DIR2 are displayed correctly, but in `case $dirnumber` it doesn't.

Is there a way to do this?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This is an extended comment (no need to upvote, the duplicate holds)

---

Generally, when you have a function where some parameters can change, you define them as argument. This way you can call your function as

```
template "/path/to/dir"
```

With a small rewrite of the function, you can now use this extra argument. Arguments to functions are referenced in the function-body using `"$1" "$2" ... "$n"` or `"$@"` or `"$*"`, depending on what you want.

Your template function could be rewritten as:

```
function template() {
    DIR="$1"
    if [[ -d "$DIR" ]]; then
        echo "$DIR Folder exists" 
    else 
        echo "Creating $DIR folder."
        mkdir -p -- "$DIR"
    fi
}
```

Now you can call your template function with

```
template "$DIR1"
```

However, when you make use of an array, you can rewrite the entire code-block much easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir_list=("/path/to/dir1" "/path/to/dir2")

select dir in "${dir_list[@]}"; do break; done

if [[ -d "${dir}" ]]; then
   echo "[INFO] Selected directory exists: $dir"
else
   echo "[INFO] Creating directory: $dir"
   mkdir -p -- "$dir"
fi
```

Comment: Please don't upvote, this is just an extended comment

Comment: @oguzismail point taken, I'll remove it and use local chat

Comment: @oguzismail I cannot start a chat with the user. He does not yet have 20 rep points (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/how-can-i-start-a-chat-with-a-particular-user)

Comment: @kvantour Thanks! You are awesome! And I learned another part of bash. :-)